# On hover p tag color is not changing

Tags: html, css

On hover I am chaning backgorund color and text color, background color is changed on hover but p tag text color is not changed.

Help me out guys

HTML

```
<div id="groupInsurance" class="group-insurance">
<img src="images/group-insurance.png" class="insuranceIcon g-img">
<p class="insuranceText">GROUP<br>INSURANCE</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#groupInsurance {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#groupInsurance:hover {
    background-color: #1E8449;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

.insuranceText {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #505050;
}
```

Comment: `#groupInsurance:hover p {color: #fff}`

Comment: Your code isn't working because you are changing the `color` of **#groupInsurance** and not the `p` contained inside it.

Comment: @AnimeshKumar in theory op approach works, it's only that the p has its own color which makes it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have a color on set on the p tag so that becomes more specific then the hover you do on the parent element. Try below

```css
#groupInsurance {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#groupInsurance:hover {
    background-color: #1E8449;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

#groupInsurance:hover > .insuranceText {
  color: #fff;
}

.insuranceText {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #505050;
}
```

```html
<div id="groupInsurance" class="group-insurance">
<img src="images/group-insurance.png" class="insuranceIcon g-img">
<p class="insuranceText">GROUP<br>INSURANCE</p>
</div>
```